# SQL - Calculate number of occurrences of previous day?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to calculate the number of people who also had occurrence the previous day on a daily basis, but I'm not sure how to do this?

Sample Table:

```
| ID |   Date    |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | 1/10/2020 |
|  1 | 1/11/2020 |
|  2 | 2/20/2020 |
|  3 | 2/20/2020 |
|  3 | 2/21/2020 |
|  4 | 2/23/2020 |
|  4 | 2/24/2020 |
|  5 | 2/22/2020 |
|  5 | 2/23/2020 |
|  5 | 2/24/2020 |
+----+-----------+
```

Desired Output:

```
|   Date    | Count |
+-----------+-------+
| 1/11/2020 |     1 |
| 2/21/2020 |     1 |
| 2/23/2020 |     1 |
| 2/24/2020 |     2 |
+-----------+-------+
```

Edit: Added desired output. The output count should be unique to the ID, not the number of date occurrences. i.e. an ID 5 can appear on this list 10 times for dates 2/23/2020 and 2/24/2020, but that would count as "1".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `lag()`:

```
select date, count(*)
from (select t.*, lag(date) over (partition by id order by date) as prev_date
      from t
     ) t
where prev_date = dateadd(day, -1, date)
group by date;
```

Comment: Hi Gordan - I just updated my sample table and added a desired output table. Would you mind taking a look please?

Comment: also, since you are very knowledgeable with SQL, could you recommend any sites to practice/improve sql?

Comment: @Empyz . . . I think you changed the question substantially, which should normally be done as a new question.  But the modification is pretty trivial, so I just adjusted the answer.